# how to make a responsive vertical video on html css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've to insert a vertical video on my website built using html css. the video must be in left side and it should be responsive. This code is displaying the vertical video on left side but on mobile it is not responsive. what I've to change here to make it responsive.

```html
<div class="vert_video">
<video width="320" height="540" controls>
  <source src="vertical_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

When i change width to 100% it shows the video on entire screen which looks weird on desktop. help me to make this video responsive.

Comment: Please review this answer I wrote for someone else. It will be useful for your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614952/bootstrap-4-embed-responsive-video-with-controls/64625271#64625271

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add `vert_video` class to `video` element.

```html
<div>
<video class="vert_video" controls>
  <source src="vertical_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

Then, add `media` queries to your css file. In your `media` queries, you can set `max-width` or `width`, which would be useful for you.

```css
/*this query will apply for the devices those have width smaller than 480px*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .vert_video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.vert_video {
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this property in css to set your video's width and height based on device width and length

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 520px){

     /* change the width and height of your video here using video property or the video containing class
        it will update the width and height as soon the width of device will go less 
        than 520px,  most of cell phones have width less than 520px(you can change 
        that too)
     */

}
```